# Calculate how long I was sitting at my computer

Tags: 13.04

Is there a way to find out, how long I was sitting at my computer all together?

maybe the time the mouse did move or keyboard input is recorded somewhere?

I tried RSI-Break, which seems to record something like that, but it is quite confusing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when you log in is recorded, would that be good enough?

Comment: no, that would record the time the machine is online, not the time I really work at it

Answer (score 0):

```
a=0
while true;do
    [[ $(qdbus org.gnome.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.GetActive) == "false" ]] && a=$[ $a + 1 ]
    echo $a >.AwakeTime.txt
    sleep 1
done
```

It's a hack but that gives a way of keeping track of how long the screen saver was not active. modify to taste (eg, poll every 60 seconds, run in background from autostart etc) to view the time, just run `cat .AwakeTime.txt`. You can place a desktop file in `~/.config/autostart` to launch this script on startup. you could reset the time in the middle of a logged in session with `killall myscript.sh && /path/to/myscript.sh& disown`